# Can Collatz conjecture be formulated as totality problem for a 2-tag system?

Tags: number-theory, collatz-conjecture, decidability

I have just read about Terence Tao's approaches to Collatz conjecture, and I have a stupid question.

If binary representations of numbers in the hailstone sequence for Collatz conjecture can be written as a $2$-tag system ($a \to bc$, $b \to a$, $c \to aaa$), and $m$-tag systems are Turing complete for $m>1$, and Collatz conjecture is a sort of halting problem in this framework (there is a halting criterion), and "deciding whether a particular algorithm for Turing machine will/won't halt on every input" is a totality problem, which is also undecidable — can a proof of undecidability of Collatz conjecture be approached this way? 
What is the major problem with this line of thought?

Comment: No question is stupid. Yes it can be written as $2$-tag system: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#As_a_tag_system

Comment: But if it is a totality problem for a 2-tag system, and 2-tag systems are Turing complete, and totality problems are undecidable — why it cannot be definitely considered undecidable?

Comment: Undecidable: that means there is no  algorithm for totality of all 2-tag systems.  But there are some 2-tag systems for which there is an algorithm.  So the problem is: to decide whether there is such an algorithm for this Collatz 2-tag system.

Comment: Work has shown that the conjecture sits within a larger family of problems, and the family is undecidable.